# Error Merger PDF (variable no definida)

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

El resultado final que estoy buscando es tener el siguiente Script de Python y pasarle parametros (ruta seleccionada, nombre de archivo de salida) desde una interfaz de C# usando Dynamic, el problema lo tengo con el Scrip de Python.

```
from os import listdir,mkdir
from os.path import isfile, join,exists
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

#Ruta del directorio a iterar archivos pdf (pasar parametros desde C#)
path = "C:\ArchivosPDF"
def folder(path):

    milista = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and '.pdf' in f]

#Nombre del archivo final
resultFile = "ArchivoDeSalida"
if '.pdf' not in resultFile:
    resultFile += '.pdf'

#Union de los archivos pdf
merger = PdfMerger() 
for pdf in milista: **#En esta linea me dice que el nombre no esta definido**
    merger.append(path)+'\\'+pdf


#Si el directorio no existe, entonces crea uno
if not exists(folder+'\\Output'):
    mkdir(folder+'\\Output')

#Escribe el archivo final en el directorio
merger.write(folder+'\\Output\\'+resultFile)
merger.close()
```

El error que me salta es que milista no esta definida, porque me da este error?
Alguna idea como solucionarlo?

Comment: veo una definicion de una funcion folder a la cual le pasas el parametro path, pero no veo el retorno ni el uso ... o me equivoco ... pregunto por que tampoco soy experto en python

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Tendria que usar en lugar de path, folder ya que a esta funcion le paso el parametro y poner un return al final?

Comment: cuando lo implementas yo tengo algo asi: https://onecompiler.com/python/422w4vesb

Comment: me dices si te funciona ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover funciona a la perfección. Pregunta cual es la diferencia de mover el directory_path y merge_pdfs al final a diferencia de como lo tenia yo al inicio?

Comment: ok revisa si la respuesta de aportugal te sirve tambien y te recomiendo marcarla como respondidas, si aun asi consiredas que no... me avisas para agregar mi respuesta es que acabo de salir de la oficina y voy conduciendo

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover ambas funcionan muy bien las dos me sirven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) La función nunca retorna `milista`, ni mucho menos la recoges en el programa principal (por eso el mensaje de error que comentas).
(2) El `if` despues de `resultFile = "ArchivoDeSalida"` no tiene ninguna razón para existir.
(3) Las rutas deben concatenarse con `os.path.join()`
(4) En esta línea: `merger.append(path)+'\\'+pdf`, solo estás adjuntando el directorio de origen, dejando el **pdf** por fuera (está fuera del paréntesis).
(5) [os.makedirs()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) puede crear la ruta de destino recursivamente, sin necesidad de testear si existe o no.

Acostúmbrate a tener un bloque de variables, así es fácil cambiarlas:

Corrigiendo:

```python
from os import listdir, makedirs
from os.path import isfile, join
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

def folder(path):
    return [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and '.pdf' in f]

# Variables
dir_input = "C:\\ArchivosPDF" # Usar doble barra \\
dir_output = "C:\\ArchivosPDF\\Output"
resultFile = "ArchivoDeSalida.pdf"

# Union de los archivos pdf
merger = PdfMerger() 
for pdf in folder(dir_input):
    merger.append(join(dir_input, pdf))

# Crea el directorio de destino, si no existe
makedirs(dir_output, exist_ok=True)

# Escribe el archivo final en el directorio
merger.write(join(dir_output, resultFile))
merger.close()
```